Right approach to react application development
I am trying to learn react and wanted to get an informed opinion on how to best create an application using react.
I learned Reusability is a crucial aspect of React.js development. Meaning the ability to use the same component in multiple places within an application or even in different projects. I wanted to understand this in greater detail.
For understanding purposes, let say my application manages employee.
I create a functional component that has entry field for employee name, address, department, manager, etc.
This functional component can be used in AddEmployee page and UpdateEmployee page like so
export default function AddEmployee () {
    .
    .
    return (
        <Employee data={null} display={toDisplay} />
    );
}

export default function UpdateEmployee () {
    .
    .
    return (
        <Employee data={myData} display={toDisplay} />
    );
}

similarly I can create a  function component for table that does sorting, pagination, edit and delete where ever table is needed in the application, like so
<Table columns={columns} data={data} flag={isActive} sortBy={sortBy} />

Is my understanding of reusability right or is there more to reusability.
Also if there are other things I should keep in mind while creating a react application that is different from angular please let me know.
Thanks

Your understanding is right! Keep coding and you'll find what is easiest for you.

@foxyz Thanks, the article I was reading on react went on and on about reusability of react. Similar feature is also available in angular so i was curious if there was more to it

Yeah your understanding is correct. To put it a little bit abstractly, reusability is to use the same template (component) and configure it based on the context. The example you provided - configuring the component using props, is exact the example of this principle.
Also there are some advanced concepts, like react hooks, which allow you to share data between components (not just passing props from parent to child). You can find many good videos and articles on this topic, but they may not explicitly mention the concept of reusability behind it. Keeping this in mind will help you have a better understanding.
Also, if you are just starting to learn react, you might want to familiarise yourself with important concepts like state management (like useState) and side effects (like useEffect)
Happy coding!
